# Eclipse package explorer project structure failed

Tags: android, eclipse, package-explorer

After I left my Computer in standby, Eclipse (Android SDK Plugin) told me that it cannot save the project (because my NAS has to start up). But then I saw the project structure was failed like you can see [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77004365/failed.JPG). Before it was like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77004365/correct.JPG) (example from another project). I tried restarting Eclipse and importing the project again. How can I change it back?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try these steps from menu option:

```
Project > Clean
```

once its done build the project

```
Project > Build All
```

Hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: After running Project > Clean, it has become messier than before (like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77004365/new.JPG)). And, the Option "Build All" is grey and cannot be used... When I use "Build Project" instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Fixed it by getting in the Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source and adding the /gen and the /src folder. Then I used Project -> Clean. Thx

Comment: Your .classpath file must have failed to be written to disk properly.